# How to search for a matching pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search a string for a pattern in the format

```
{{ Control :: 123 }}
or
{{Control::123}}
or
{{ Control ::123 }}
or
{{Control :: 123}}
```

Basically the space can be anywhere but it will have to start with the double open curly brackets, followed for the word "Control" followed by :: followed by a number ending with double closing curly brackets.

Here is what I have done

```
$pattern = '/{{ ?% ?Control ?:: ?([1-9]+([0-9]{1,2})?) ?% ?}}/i';
$subject = 'This is my subject for "{{ Control:: 132}}" ';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

I need to be able to return the found pattern i.e `{{ Control:: 132}}`. Then I need to be able to find the number `132`

What am I doing wrong here for this not to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because you didn't escape "{" and "}".Additionally you can write it more simply.
Try this:

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s?Control\s?::\s?(\d+)\s?\}\}/i';
```

Note that it might be enhanced to accept more than 1 space everywhere:

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*Control\s*::\s*(\d+)\s*\}\}/i';
```

Comment: the second pattern you gave me will not work if there is no space. I am trying to match if a space exists or not. But when I changed it a bit it worked. here is what I have changed it to ` $pattern = '/\{\{\s*+Control\s*+::\s*+(\d+)\s*+\}\}/i';`

Comment: @MikeA Indeed you're right. Sorry, I edit my answer.